# C#-like language without curly brackets

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I'm enjoying C# as a programming language very much. 
But one thing I would really like to see in it is a way of separating blocks in the way it is done in Python - with identation.

I had a brief look on IronPython, but it seems to bring much more python stuff than I need.

Does anybody know an easy way to use identation instead of curly brackets?

UPD:
Please compare class definition in C#:

```
class Foo
{
    public string bar() 
    {
        return "smth";
    }
}
```

and Python:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        return "smth"
```

Look how much redundant space is used in C# variant. My goal is to use best from both languages.

Comment: Not a real question, and um....use VB.NET?

Comment: Could you provide some hints on what you are trying to accomplish and why? What are your requirements? @series0ne don't you think <Foo> / End <Foo> is even worse than braces? The question asks for indentation as structuring concept.

Comment: What's wrong with curly brackets anyway? They give a clear indication of where a block starts and ends. Considering that C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, TypeScript, Dart (to name a few) use them, I'd say there were more reasons for them than against!

Comment: @SimonOpelt, Ok admittedly you don't need to use indentation in VB.NET, and it's rather long winded in the way it begins and ends blocks. I wasn't addressing the idea of using indentation for structuring...I was addressing the point that VB.NET doesn't use curly brackets.

Comment: I don't think this should be on hold: 'what's a CLR language with python style block syntax' is a perfectly objective question - the opinion part is only whether or not people want that, and OP clearly does.

Answer (score 2):

[Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) is a .Net language with static typing. It uses the CLR so you can share with other .Net code, including c#; it works with winforms and system.io and other familiar libraries.  It looks a lot like python:  Compare these this in Boo:

```
internal class TileBytes:

    public Size as int

    public def constructor(size as int):
         Size = size

    public def Generate(tile as Tile) as (byte):
       buffer as (byte) = array(byte, ((Size * Size) * 3))
       for u in range(0, Size):
         for v in range(0, Size):
            pixelColor as Color32 = GetColor(tile, u, v)
            bufferidx as int = (3 * ((u * Size) + v))
            buffer[bufferidx] = pixelColor.r
            buffer[(bufferidx + 1)] = pixelColor.g
            buffer[(bufferidx + 2)] = pixelColor.b
       return buffer

     public def GetColor(tile as Tile, u as int, v as int) as Color32:
        h as int = (0 if (v > (Size / 2.0)) else 2)
        w as int = (0 if (u > (Size / 2.0)) else 1)
        tc as TileCorner = ((h cast TileCorner) + w)
    return tile[tc].GetPixel(v, (Size - (u + 1)))
```

to this in C#

```
class TileBytes
{
public int Size;
public TileBytes(int size)
{
    Size = size;
}

public byte[] Generate(Tile tile)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Size * Size * 3];
    for (int u = 0; u < Size; u++)
    {
        for (int v = 0; v<Size; v++)
        {
            Color32 pixelColor = GetColor (tile, u, v);
            int bufferidx = 3 * (( u * Size) + v);
            buffer[bufferidx] = pixelColor.r;
            buffer[bufferidx + 1] = pixelColor.g;
            buffer[bufferidx + 2] = pixelColor.b;               
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}

public Color32 GetColor(Tile tile, int u, int v)
{
    int h = v > Size / 2.0 ? 0 : 2;
    int w = u > Size / 2.0 ? 0 : 1;
    TileCorner tc = (TileCorner) h + w;
    return tile[tc].GetPixel(v,  Size - (u + 1));
}
}
```

Boo is also an active [open source project](https://github.com/bamboo/boo)

Answer (score 0):

```
return someValue == true ? DoSomething() : DoSomethingElse()
```

instead of

```
if (someValue == true)
{
    DoSomething();
}
else
{
    DoSoemthingElse();
}
```

xDDD

Answer (score -1):

To 'save' space in your code you could always adapt this style of coding:

```
private void DoWork() {
 if(true) {
  DoMoreWork();
 } else {
  DoLessWork();
 }
}
```

I've been using it for almost a year now and am very happy with the readability of my code.

Comment: Yep, I am aware of such style. But still not as elegant as in Python.

Comment: Also, not a stylistic convention in C#...this is more a convention used in Java/JavaScript. StyleCop will complain about this if you even decide to use that

Comment: http://kotaku.com/454293019 is what I strongly admire. I try to use this coding style everywhere I go. C, C++, C#, doesn't matter. It's clear, clean and powerful.